# Implementing EF6 using NuGet packages

Tags: c#, nuget, entity-framework-6

I am moving to EF6 I have tried with latest NuGet Packages.

I have Main Application and other supported application underneath same project solutions.

Other supported applications and the one in which entity framework reside (server side) are converted successfully but while giving the reference of all these project dll to main project when I give reference of OpenRiaServices I get an error "Exception has been thrown by target of an invocation".

All projects follow client-server architecture.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's interesting.  Did you have a question to ask?

Comment: The error that I am getting "Exception has been thrown by target of an invocation", I am unable to resolve it. So the question is how do I resolve it?